# How do I make a "view more..." link for Drupal blocks?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-modules

I have a simple drupal block which displays top terms from a given vocabulary, ordered by the frequency of use of those terms (ie, most popular tags). I would like to add a "view more..." link at the end of this block, which links to the "page" mode of this view, listing all terms, instead of just the top N terms. How would I go about doing this? Is there a built in views feature or add-on module that can do something like this?

So far I have found out how to add custom HTML at the end of the block, but I know that's hackish.

I am currently running views 2 with Drupal 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the settings for the view (block display), click on "More link". The page will appear as

[image: Views setting]

Comment: That does it, thanks! Views is amazing yet again. (though it would be more intuitive if I could think in the 4th dimension).